# How to fix scheduled query in BigQuery not returning results correctly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've written a few queries for BigQuery in standard SQL that are scheduled to run every day at 5AM UTC+2, but they return null or empty results.

Specifically, the queries are looking at the previous day's data, so they take the `@run_date` parameter and subtract 1 day to get the correct date to be used as the `_table_suffix` (the data is column partitioned).

I've tested running the queries manually, both from console (switching out `@run_date` for `CURRENT_DATE()` ) and by manually scheduling a backfill, using the current date as the run date.

```sql
WITH installs AS (
    SELECT 
        COUNTIF(event_name="first_open" AND app_info.install_source="manual_install") AS manualInstalls,
        COUNTIF(event_name="first_open" AND app_info.install_source <> "manual_install") AS appStoreOtherInstalls,
        COUNTIF(event_name="first_open") AS installsTotal,
        COUNTIF(event_name="app_remove" AND user_id IS NOT NULL) AS uninstallRegistered,
        COUNTIF(event_name="app_remove" AND user_id IS NULL) AS uninstallUnregistered,
        COUNTIF(event_name="app_remove") AS uninstallsTotal
    FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
    WHERE _table_suffix=CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS STRING)
),

maus AS (
    SELECT 

    COUNT( DISTINCT
        (SELECT 
            IF(
                REGEXP_CONTAINS(user_id, 
                CASE
                    WHEN user_id LIKE "+237%" THEN r"\+237((67)|(8[0-3])|(5[0-4]))"
                    WHEN user_id LIKE "+27%" THEN r"\+27((83)|(810)|(6((0[3-5])|(3([0-5]|[8-9]))|(40)|(5[5-7])))|7(1(0|[7-9])|(3|8)))"
                    WHEN user_id LIKE "+225%" THEN r"\+225(0|[4-8])[4-6]"
                    WHEN user_id LIKE "+242%" THEN r"\+24206[4-9]"
                END
                ),
            user_id, "")
        )
    ) AS mauNetwork,

    count(DISTINCT user_id) AS mau
    FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
    WHERE _table_suffix BETWEEN CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS STRING) 
    AND CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS STRING)
)

SELECT 
    CAST(FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(@run_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS STRING) AS event_date, 
    IF(installs.manualInstalls IS NOT NULL, installs.manualInstalls, 0) AS manualInstalls, 
    IF(installs.appStoreOtherInstalls IS NOT NULL, installs.appStoreOtherInstalls, 0) AS appStoreOtherInstalls,
    IF(installs.installsTotal IS NOT NULL, installs.installsTotal, 0) AS installsTotal,
    IF(installs.uninstallRegistered IS NOT NULL, installs.uninstallRegistered, 0) AS uninstallRegistered, 
    IF(installs.uninstallUnregistered IS NOT NULL, installs.uninstallUnregistered, 0) AS uninstallNotRegistered, 
    IF(installs.uninstallsTotal IS NOT NULL, installs.uninstallsTotal, 0) AS uninstallsTotal,
    IF(maus.mau IS NOT NULL, maus.mau, 0) AS mau,
    IF(maus.mauNetwork IS NOT NULL, maus.mauNetwork, 0) AS mauNetwork
FROM installs, signUps, daus, maus
```

I expected all columns to be populated, but they're zero-filled since they're null. The subquery block called `maus` does actually return results, but it has a much longer window - I suspect there's maybe something wrong with my logic around retrieving the previous day's data the way that I am.

I'd really appreciate any insight / suggestions!

Comment: Look in the query history, and see what's the date fragment used. If that is not quite visible in logs. Try to use SQL as log, to INSERT into a table the params you setup, and see how queries are launched.

Comment: @Pentium10 thanks for the response. I've taken a look at the execution plan and in each of the stages, the date is correct. For example:

`$30:user_id, $31:_TABLE_SUFFIX
FROM project.dataset.events_*
WHERE equal($31, '20190912')`

That's a valid table name and suffix. Any further suggestions?

Comment: If the dates are correct, then I would suggest querying the `installs` subquery block separately to check if you can retrieve the data you are expecting. Looking through the whole thing, I cannot see any obvious issues with it.

Comment: @pessolato thanks for checking it out, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue was that the tables were simply not available at 5am. There are two factors to consider when dealing with Firebase exports to BigQuery.

Firebase stores data for the current day in an `events_intraday_*` table, and when it decides to close off that table, it is written to a permanent `events_*` table. This process can take some time and may take a full day, though this scenario is more rare.

Then, depending on your timezone settings in Firebase itself, the tables will close even later in the day.

Basically, run the queries later and everything works as expected. Unfortunately, sometimes this still doesn't work due to processing running way later than anticipated so there are two options - write a custom scheduler that has internal logic for checking the availability of tables, or write the queries in such a way that they themselves check for data availability first.